# How to display 2 digits after comma in my formControl

Tags: angular

I have tryed to let my input with a value like '1,00', for example. However, my method is wrong, it's displaying '100' in input.

This is my html code

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>valor unitário</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="valor" prefix="R$ " mask="separator.2" thousandSeparator="." (blur)="blurValueInput('valor')" (keyup)="autoComplete('valor')"> 
    <mat-error>campo obrigatório</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

and this is my typescript code. It should display '1,00' if i let the input with a value like this '1,0'

```
constructor(private form: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.pagamentoForm = this.form.group({
      quantidade: [1, Validators.required],
      desc_produto: ['', Validators.required],
      valor: ['', Validators.required],
      desc_iti: [''],
      desc_varejo: ['']
    });
    this.descInput.nativeElement.focus();
  }

public blurValueInput(labelName: string) {
    if (this.pagamentoForm.controls[labelName].value.length - 
    this.pagamentoForm.controls[labelName].value.indexOf('.') === 2) {        
 this.pagamentoForm.controls[labelName].setValue(Number.parseFloat(this.pagamentoForm.controls[labelName].value).toFixed(2));        
      }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey google "input mask angular"

Comment: can you post some other examples so we can understand clearly what is your requirement. you can just replace comma with **zeero** for example you have posted